# Javascript redirection on WP7.1 In-App Browser

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to run a Javascript redirection code on the Window Phone 7's in-app browser, but the redirection does not seem to occur at all.

Snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sform() {
        document.forms["frm"].submit();
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="sform()">
        <form action="https://payment-endpoint-url.com" method="POST" name="frm">
        <input type="hidden" name="Ref_ID" value="***" />
    <!--- some other data that varies depending on the transaction -->
    </form>
</body>
```

I have tried every possible way to make a HTTP POST redirect using Javascript and have also tried a few IE-specific methods, but they do not work. Is there a workaround for this? Could it be a new security feature that disallows redirect?

Comment: I have made posts using the Jquery Ajax calls in the WebBrowser control in WP7, so it's technically possible. I don't know about doing so from a form.

Comment: I'm Gerry's friend. IsScriptEnabled="True" was already set. Yet it still doesn't post the form.

Comment: Can you browse the https site normally from the control? Not all SSL certificates are accepted by the phone, in particular the free ones.

Comment: I've seen an issue (currently only recerated in the emualtor) where javascript won't run on the first page that is loaded inside the WebBrowser control. Could this be the same issue?

Comment: Matt, did you manage to find a solution for the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

This code seemed to work for me:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sform() {
          document.getElementById("submit1").click();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="sform()">
    <form action="https://payment-endpoint-url.com" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="Ref_ID" value="***" />
      <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit1" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```